# How to ignore MSB4011 when running dotnet build

Tags: f#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

When I run `dotnet build` I get this warning many times:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CrossTargeting.targets(145,3):
warning MSB4011: "*.fsproj.proj-info.targets" cannot be imported again.
It was already imported at "Microsoft.Common.targets (127,3)".
This is most likely a build authoring error.
This subsequent import will be ignored.
[*.fsproj]
```

How can I prevent these warnings from displaying?

Comment: It would seem that this should be *fixed* within whatever is generating the *.fsproj.proj-info.targets files. I don't know enough about the F# build process to know where to look on GitHub.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `/nowarn:msb4011` to the command line.

```
dotnet build /nowarn:msb4011
```

Comment: Is it possible to suppress multiple warnings?

Comment: Suppress multiple warnings? Depends on platform. See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8792#issuecomment-393756980